# Does anyone have any idea what this set is?

Tags: set-identification

I am sorting sets for my grandson. Any idea about this set. I need instructions and parts but don't know the set of set group. Any help appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is

[Set# 8511 : Frost](https://brickset.com/sets/8511-1/Frost)

key part : [Trans-Light Blue Minifigure, Weapon Pike / Spear - Handle with Round End](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4497&colorID=15&in=A)

[image]